# Opening more than 10 file descriptors with ksh

Tags: io-redirection, ksh, file-descriptors

The shell syntax for opening a file for writing and using its file descriptor is:

```
exec 3>output.log
```

With bash and zsh you also can write:

```
exec 13>output.log
```

Thus, later in your script you can redirect output like this:

```
generate-partx >&3
generate-partx >&13
```

And to close them:

```
exec 3>&-
exec 13>&-
```

The original ksh (tested 88 and 93) only seems to support file descriptor numbers 0 to 9 with that syntax.

Sure, one could argue that 10 open file descriptors should be enough for everyone and/or that nobody is using ksh anymore.

But sometimes it is not and you are.

Thus, my question: How to open more than 10 file descriptors in a ksh script?

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh the fd is a 'single digit'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ksh`, you can only use single digit for explicit file descriptor. With `ksh93r` and above, you can open more than 10 file descriptor by using the form:

```
{var}>filename
```

[(`bash` and `zsh` copied this feature later)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226207/38906).

`ksh` will pick available file descriptor greater than or equal to 10, store file descriptor number in variable `var`:

```
$ exec {var1}>/tmp/test1
$ echo "$var1"
10
$ exec {var2}>/tmp/test2
$ echo "$var2"
11
```

Comment: How does close work on these fds?  `exec ${var1}>&-` doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Anirban: `exec {var1}>&-` (works in ksh, bash and zsh).