# Bash - Use automatic file descriptor creation instead of fifo

Tags: bash, file-descriptors, netcat

At the beginning, I created a small server with `netcat` and it worked well:

```
#!/bin/bash

PORT="1234";

startServer(){
    fifo="fifo/$1";
    mkfifo "$fifo";

    connected="0";

    netcat -q 0 -l -p "$PORT" < "$fifo" | while read -r line; do
        if [ "$connected" == "0" ];then
            #listen for a new connection
            startServer $(($1+1))&
            connected="1";
        fi

        #server logic goes here

    done > "$fifo";

    rm "$fifo";
}

mkdir fifo;
startServer 0;
```

It uses fifos to redirect the main loop output back to `netcat`.

Every call to `startServer` increases the value of `$1` and creates a fifo file `fifo/$1`.

But I want to use [bash's automatic file descriptor creation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/226165) to get rid of `fifo` files and the parameter of `startServer`.

After multiple attempts, here is my current attempt at modifying the `startServer` function. I can receive lines from the client but unfortunately it does not receive anything back. I am confused about what is wrong.

```
startServer(){
    connected="0";

    #create file descriptor and read output from main loop
    exec {fd}> >( netcat -q 0 -l -p "$PORT" | while read -r line; do
        if [ "$connected" == "0" ];then
            #listen for a new connection
            startServer&
            connected="1";
        fi

        #server logic goes here

    done ) >&$fd;

    #close file descriptor
    exec {fd}<&-;
    exec {fd}>&-;
}
```

Also, I cannot use netcat's "-e" option since it is not available in the netcat-openbsd package.

Comment: Allocating a file descriptor doesn't allocate a buffer for it to refer to.

Comment: @chepner The redirection >( ... ) or <( ... ) should allocate a buffer.

Comment: That's not a redirection; it's a process substitution, which is effectively just special syntax for a fifo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot set and use `fd` in the same command; you are effectively doing `exec {fd}> ... >&$fd`.  What can work is creating the bash fifo/pipe first, using some simple command like `:`. Eg:

```
startServer(){
    local connected=0 fd
    exec {fd}<> <(:)
    nc -q 0 -l -p "$PORT" <&$fd | 
    while read -r line
    do  if [ "$connected" == "0" ]
        then startServer $(($1+1)) &
             connected="1"
        fi
        echo server $1 logic goes here
    done >&$fd
    exec {fd}<&-
}
```

Comment: Nice!   no-op FTW