# What does `exec {STDIN}>&0` do?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I saw this in a bash script, and trying to make sense of it:

```
exec {STDIN}>&0
exec {STDOUT}>&1
exec {STDERR}>&2
```

Are the `{STDIN}`, `{STDOUT}` etc "magic strings" recognized by `exec` directive in bash scripts?

Isn't STDOUT already set to `&1` (and STDERR set to `&2`, ...) anyway?

What do these lines do?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226164/342404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> **REDIRECTION**
>
> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected using a
>   special  notation  interpreted by the shell.  [...]
>
> Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be
>   preceded by a word of the form **{***varname***}**.  In this case,
>   for  each redirection operator  except  >&- and <&-, the shell will allocate a 
>   file descriptor greater than or equal to 10 and assign it to *varname*.
>   If >&-  or  <&-  is  preceded  by **{***varname***}**, the value of
>   *varname* defines the file descriptor to close.

So the lines in your example:

```
exec {STDIN}>&0
exec {STDOUT}>&1
exec {STDERR}>&2
```

have the effect of assigning three new file descriptors that are duplicates of the current descriptors 0, 1 and 2, and assigning the values of those new descriptors to the shell variables `$STDIN`, `$STDOUT` and `$STDERR` respectively.  After those commands have been executed you should be able to see the values of the duplicate descriptors:

```
$ echo $STDIN $STDOUT $STDERR
10 11 12
```

The most likely reason for doing this is to save the current disposition of stdin, stdout and stderr so that the script can freely redirect descriptors 0, 1 and 2 to various places as needed by some parts of the script, and then restore them to their original targets by doing something like:

```
exec 0>&$STDIN
exec 1>&$STDOUT
exec 2>&$STDERR
```